# how to add two xaml page with same name and separate code file behind in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

Hi I want to have two different layouts, one for mobile other for pc and for this I want to add two xaml page with same name MainPage.xaml and code file behind `MainPage.xaml.cs`. One page added into `DeviceFamily-Mobile` folder and other in main area of project.

Now when I run the app it gives this error:

**"Type 'MainPage' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types"**

To overcome this problem I add parameter in constructor of mainpage for desktop. Now project runs successfully and both page and code works good but I just noticed that parameterized constructor of desktop page not being called...

**Now my summarized question is how can i add two page with same name and different code file behind for specific device family.**

I have search a lot but did not get answer of my question. 
Please suggest me any solution of my problem any tip.

Thanks

**Note: One more thing, I don't want different xaml page with same one code file.**

Answer (score 2):

i) To create a page which targets different devices the XAML file is named using a specific syntax based on MRT. We have tooling support for this in Visual Studio:

First, create a new folder in your project by right clicking on the project->Add New Item->New Folder. This folder needs to be named to target a particular device family – in this case we will use Mobile (which includes Phone) using ‘DeviceFamily-Mobile’.The tailored XAML view is then created in Visual Studio using the ‘XAML view’ template. Select the folder you added, then right click->Add New Item->XAML View. Make sure you edit the name to be MainPage.xaml (by default it will be named MainPage1.xaml). You need to use the same name so that the code behind will be shared an the page correctly loaded.

Both views share the same code behind (MainPage.xaml.cs in the above example), and creating an event handler in one can also be used in the other view. When the app is run, Universal Windows will pick the correct view based on the device family that the app is being run on.

ii) If you want to special case code for a particular view you can test for the devicefamily as follows

if (Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily == "Windows.Mobile")

Comment: perfect answer but u don't have seen my question Note... "One more thing, I don't want different xaml page with same one code file." You are all telling correct if i want 2 separate xaml with one shared cs file. But i wanna 2 separate xaml with seprate cs page file. Is it possible in uwp?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. You must create 2 difference `Page` to have difference code behind.

I would suggest:

- Refactor your code behind using dependency injection and interface so it adaptive to device family

Comment: yes i have two page created separately but it gives ".ctor" error. unable to understand how to resolve this constructor error. And what you trying to say about dependency injection please give me little bit detail. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Pages in UWP are partial witch means you can create a new cs and just write `public partial class MainPage{}` and continue the class from there. You could then use conditional compilation.

As I searched a bit I couldn't find any conditional compiling in UWP but only for Universal(Second link). But the first link might help.

[Three ways to set specific DeviceFamily XAML Views in UWP](http://igrali.com/2015/08/02/three-ways-to-set-specific-devicefamily-xaml-views-in-uwp/)

[Conditional Compilation in Universal Apps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/845485/Conditional-Compilation-in-Universal-Apps)

Comment: I have seen first link already but they are only creating xaml pages with only one MainPage.xaml.cs file. I want two files separate for each device family as i mention in my question.

Comment: Not possible. You can you the partial though to create two files of MainPage and then in each file you write Device specific code.